# Submit several changes to Datacontext Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, transactions

I'm working on an application. Net using MVC3 and Entity Framework to access an SQL Server database.
I need to develop a view that lists the products in a table where the user can add, edit and delete products without these changes is recorded in thedb until it clicks a button to save the list.
knowing there is a data layer and business layer.
I do not know how to handle this case!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Keep the data in memory until the user clicks save then put it in the database

Comment: I have nothing done until now.
I'm seeking an optimal solution before start coding.
The problem is that i have to keep the data layer independent of the presentation layer and at the same time i must manage data concurrency

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is still relevant, but you could do this:

- Use Add(), Update() and Delete() to perform all the changes to the in-memory collection of objects that Entity Framework holds. Don't call SaveChanges().
- Bind your save button to a method that calls SaveChanges() on the context. Now every entity you added/modified/deleted will be changed in the database as well (and if something changes, it will roll back all these changes).

Sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. My question still relevant. but working with the same Datacontext is not recomanded as i know. The problem is it will be over 100 user working at the same time and the application will be deployed under Windows Azure.